# Is it possible to perform a LINQ aggregate over a collection of one type to a different result type?

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I would like to use a single LINQ aggregate over a collection of (latitude, longitude) pairs and produce two (latitude, longitude) pairs:

```
public Location {
   public double Latitude;
   public double Longitude;
}

List<Location> border = ...;
```

I can easily obtain a minimum (latitude, longitude) pair by:

```
var minBorder =  border.Aggregate( new Location()
                                 { Latitude = double.MaxValue, Longitude = double.MaxValue },
                                 (current, next) =>
                                   new Location()
                                   {
                                     Latitude = (next.Latitude < current.Latitude) ? next.Latitude : current.Latitude,
                                     Longitude = (next.Longitude < current.Longitude) ? next.Longitude : current.Longitude
                                   }) ;
```

If possible, I would like to use a single aggregate to return two Locations; a minimum (latitude, longitude) pair and a maximum (latitude, longitude) pair instead of one.

If I declare a class for results:

```
public class BorderBounds {

   public double MinLatitude;
   public double MinLongitude;

   public double MaxLatitude;
   public double MaxLongitude;
}
```

and modify the aggregate:

```
var borderBounds =  border.Aggregate( new Location()
                                 { Latitude = double.MaxValue, Longitude = double.MaxValue },
                                 (current, next) =>
                                   new BorderBounds()
                                   {
                                    ...
                                   }) ;
```

the `(current, next)` parameters are assumed to be of type `BorderBounds` instead of `Location`.

Is there a way to construct such an aggregate? Would it be best to simply convert this to a `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it. I would suggest making the bounds mutable, or making a mutable bounds builder that can create a bounds object afterwards, just to save on the unnecessary memory allocation:

```
locations.Aggregate(new Bounds(), (bounds, location) =>
        {
            if (bounds.MinLat > location.Latitude) bounds.MinLat = location.Latitude;
            if (bounds.MaxLat < location.Latitude) bounds.MaxLat = location.Latitude;
            if (bounds.MinLon > location.Longitude) bounds.MinLon = location.Longitude;
            if (bounds.MaxLon < location.Longitude) bounds.MaxLon = location.Longitude;
            return bounds;
        });
```

And the classes

```
internal class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

internal class Bounds
{
    public Bounds()
    {
        MinLat = double.MaxValue;
        MaxLat = double.MinValue;
        MinLon = double.MaxValue;
        MaxLon = double.MinValue;
    }

    public double MinLat { get; set; }
    public double MaxLat { get; set; }
    public double MinLon { get; set; }
    public double MaxLon { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This will return 0 instead of the actual minimum or maximum for some collections.

Comment: Not it won't. But it will mess up if there are no locations. Ideally it should throw in that circumstance.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Missed the assignment in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
border
    .Aggregate(new BorderBounds() 
             { MinLatitude = double.MaxValue, 
               MinLongitude = double.MaxValue, 
               MaxLongitude = double.MinValue, 
               MaxLatitude = double.MinValue }, 
               (current, next) => new BorderBounds {
                   MinLatitude = next.Latitude < current.MinLatitude ? next.Latitude : current.MinLatitude,
                   MinLongitude = next.Longitude < current.MinLongitude ? next.Longitude : current.MinLongitude,
                   MaxLatitude = next.Latitude > current.MaxLatitude ? next.Latitude : current.MaxLatitude,
                   MaxLongitude = next.Longitude > current.MaxLongitude ? next.Longitude : current.MaxLongitude
                } 
     );
```

The return type of an Aggregate function is the same as the seed passed in, and not of the collection itself.

I'm assuming you're constructing something like a bounding box here.

Comment: I am constructing a bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

```
var borderBounds = border.Aggregate(new BorderBounds 
{
    MinLatitude = double.MaxValue,
    MinLongitude = double.MaxValue,
    MaxLatitude = double.MinValue,
    MaxLongitude = double.MinValue
}, 
(current, next) => new BorderBounds
{
    MinLatitude = Math.Min(current.MinLatitude, next.Latitude),
    MinLongitude = Math.Min(current.MinLongitude, next.Longitude),
    MaxLatitude = Math.Max(current.MaxLatitude, next.Latitude),
    MaxLongitude = Math.Max(current.MaxLongitude, next.Longitude),
});
```